# How do I know which Visa Type I need to visit Switzerland?

Tags: visas, schengen, switzerland, business-travel

I'm currently in the hiring process with a company based in Switzerland. I will be working remotely from the US but they want me to go to their headquarters to get to know the team/work together/etc.. for only a month. So would I need a Work or Business visa ?

Comment: This answer may vary for people of different nationalities, and you didn't indicate your citizenship. And regardless of that, you should always consult with the Swiss embassy or consulate, as they will have firsthand knowledge of the paperwork you need.

Comment: This sounds like something your new employer should be assisting you with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A business visa (type C visa) allows you to enter a country temporarily to conduct business there, such as buying stuff, meeting with collaborators etc. Business visa are usually valid for 90 days, like tourist visas, and they do not allow residence. Whether you actually need to apply to the [Swiss embassy in Washington](http://www.eda.admin.ch/eda/en/home/reps/nameri/vusa/ref_visinf/visusa.html.html) to obtain a business visa [depends on your nationality](http://www.bfm.admin.ch/bfm/en/home/themen/einreise/merkblatt_einreise.html).

A work visa (type D visa) allows you to stay in the country for more than 90 days to conduct business.

See also [this FAQ](http://www.bfm.admin.ch/content/bfm/en/home/themen/einreise/faq.faq_3.html#a_faq_3) for the difference between the two visas, and for links to the respective applications.

Comment: Great answer, thanks :). I spoke to the counsel and was told that if I work for more than 8 days I NEED a work visa, otherwise it's a business visa.